# What does "grid search" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does **grid search** mean in the [following sentence](http://www.aqmd.gov/docs/default-source/aqmd-forms/Permit/ab3205-request-form.pdf)?

> To expedite your request for **grid search**, please fill out this form completely, one form for each school site, and mail it with the fee in the amount of $310.53<sup>1</sup>.

Comment: The small, raised "1" at the end of the number is not part of the number.  It is "superscript" -- in other words, it is small and raised, and not part of the rest of the line of text.  There are three main uses of superscripted text:  1)  As in this example, as hyperlinks to footnotes or endnotes.  In this example, footnote 1 explains why the fee is required, and when it might change.  2)  To indicate that one number is raised to a power.  For example, 3² = 9.  3)  In Physics, to indicate particular properties of certain atoms or other particles.

Answer (score 2):

> PURSUANT TO CALIFORNIA EDUCATION CODE 17213, THIS REQUEST IS FOR THE IDENTIFICATION OF ALL AQMD PERMITTED FACILITIES WITH THE POTENTIAL TO EMIT HAZARDOUS AIR POLLUTANTS LOCATED WITHIN 1/4 MILE OF A SCHOOL SITE

AQMD is 'South Coast Air Quality Management District' - basically just in case there are any air-polluting sites within 1/4 mile of a school, you have to pay for AQMD to search the ground for such plants. They have divided the ground into grids, based on squares of 1/4 mile radius.

[AQMD](http://www.aqmd.gov/docs/default-source/aqmd-forms/Permit/ab3205-request-form.pdf?sfvrsn=2)

Comment: Is there other meanings for this term in other contexts?